# What is the meaning of Reference of type base and object of derive class

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Say

```
class Animal
{
  public Animal()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Animal constructor");
   }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
public Dog()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Dog constructor");
   }
   }
```

Now the question is here if I write a code like this

```
Animal A = new Animal();
```

a Object  is created in the heap and our referrence variable "A" point to that location in the heap.

Now If I write a code like this

```
Animal B = new Dog();
```

Then here how does the Referrence B point to the Object Dog?

I am stuck with visual illustration of this concept. many a time I read that "We have an object of type Animal, but it references an object of type Dog". But what does it really mean?

Any elaborate answer would be good. As I am learning few of the .net (OOPS) concept deeply.

[image: Animal and Dog Object]

Comment: both your `Dog` and `Animal` classes are missing a constructor and will not compile.

Comment: Now it is fine, Sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, then I think it is clear.

Comment: I've added more details about the internals of objects to my answer, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the classes (not their instances), then I would rather draw the picture like this:

[image]

Which means the `Dog` class has usually more methods and properties than the `Animal` class (for instance, a dog can `bark` (method) and has four `legs` (property)). And of course, additional memory has to be reserved when this class is instantiated. Imagine that the base classes methods and properties are created first, then the derived methods and properties are created in memory:

```
class Dog : Animal 
{ 
    public Dog() 
    { 
        legs = 4;
        Console.WriteLine("Dog constructor"); 
    } 


    public int legs { get; private set; }

    public void bark()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("grrrwoof!"); 
    }
}
```

If you instantiate a `Dog` and assign it to an `Animal` reference variable as you did, then this reference can only access the methods an `Animal` has. Despite of this fact, the entire `Dog` object is still kept in memory:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
Animal a = (Animal)d;
```

In other words, `d` is able to do the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number of legs: {0}", d.legs.ToString())); 
d.bark();
```

but `a` can't do that, because those "features" are not defined within the `Animal` class.

What is now important to know is that not all kinds of casts are allowed. It is always allowed to cast from a `Dog` to an `Animal`, because this is safe, but you can't cast an `Animal` to a `Dog` implicitly, so the follwing code throws an invalid cast exception:

```
Dog dogRef2 = a; // not allowed
```

If you know what you're doing (i.e. if you know for sure that `a` contains an instance of `Dog`), then you are allowed to cast explicitly as follows:

```
Dog dogRef2 = (Dog)a; // allowed
```

and you can access the properties and methods afterwards:

```
dogRef2.bark(); // works
```

This works, because the compiler and the runtime always store the methods and properties in the same structured way in memory and also create an internal descriptor to find it when it is referenced.

Note that this isn't always safe, for instance if you try the following:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Dog dogRef2 = (Dog)a; // Invalid cast exception
```

**Why?** Because `new Animal()` hasn't created the method `bark` and the property `legs`, it has just created an instance of `Animal` (contains neither the property `legs` nor the method `bark`).

**More info:** If you want to find out more about the internal structure (how objects are created and stored), check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx). Here is an example for a memory layout, taken from there:
[image: EEClasses]

You can see that [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) are used to build up the chain from the base classes instance objects to the derived classes instance objects.

Comment: Excellent illustration and answer, this is all about base class and casting etc. this is fine but my question is How come the A referrence point to the Dog object? Let me give you some more When we write ` Animal A = new Animal();` A ref point to the new object Animal which is just created. But ` Animal A = new Dog();` then how ref variable A point to Dog as well as Animal object. As we know that depends upon our coding it invoke base class methods or parent class methods. So that is exactly my question

Comment: It is the way the compiler and runtime system instantiates the object: Imagine the base class (Animal) is always instantiated first and stored in memory, then the derived classes methods and properties are stored. And there needs to be a kind of internal descriptor in memory too, which is used to find all the methods and properties of the base class and the derived class. Now, because the base class comes first, the Animal reference variable finds the (base) methods and properties it expects and so does the Dog reference variable (because of the internal descriptor structure).

Comment: Thanks Matt, It is indeed a nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> how does the Referrence B point to the Object Dog?

Same way reference A points to object Animal. I think you are maybe confusing how classes are related via inheritance vs instantiated.

Creating a new instance of a class which derives from another has no reference to any instances of it's base class e.g.

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Animal b = new Dog();
```

`Animal b` has no reference or link to `Animal a`, they are 2 separate *instances* of type `Animal`. The difference is `Animal b` is actually of type `Dog` but has been *cast* as an `Animal`. When you cast up/down the inheritance hierarchy then the reference doesn't change (think the technical term for this is called *reference conversion*) therefore:

```
Dog d = (Dog)b;
```

Still refers to the same object as `Animal b` does, it's just a different *type* of reference.

Comment: Yes true, but in this case what is the advantages we have for creating `Animal b = new Dog();` Why if we arite a code like b.m1(); it will call Animal method if we don't use virtual override?

Comment: Can Anybody see a picture? I have uploaded a picture of my understanding of the "Animal / Dog: object. Can anbody see this. I don't in my browser.

Comment: @Debhere it depends on the context, in most cases it's usually to avoid explicit casting.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Animal
{
    public Animal() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Animal constructor"); 
    }

    public  void  show()        
    {
        Console.WriteLine("animal");
    }

}

class Dog : Animal 
{ 
    public Dog() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Dog constructor"); 
    }

    public  void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal B = new Dog();

        B.show();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

In the above Program

```
B.show();
```

will call the base class `show()`

why, because, the `Dog()`, will also be having `show()` method ,this gets invoked since the reference type used was Animal , if you still want to call `show()` of Dog 's class use virtual and override concept

Answer (score 0):

Animal B = new Dog();

new operator returns the ref of Dog(); which gets stored in Animal B  , so the ref b is pointing to dog